# How to initialize library extension correctly?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to use cytoscape.js extension named edgehandler in my project but it doesn't work. All I need is on that demo: [DEMO EDGEHANDLES](https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-edgehandles/demo-snap.html)

I've add script:

```
<script src="{% static "js/cytoscape-edgehandles.js"%}"></script>
```

And initialization from [GitHub cytoscape.js-edgehandles](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles) right under cytoscape.js variable:

```
let defaults = {
    preview: true, 
    hoverDelay: 150, 
    handleNodes: 'node', 
    snap: false, 
    snapThreshold: 50, 
    snapFrequency: 15, 
    noEdgeEventsInDraw: false, 
    disableBrowserGestures: true, 
    handlePosition: function( node ){
      return 'middle top'; 
    },
    handleInDrawMode: false,
  };
  
  let eh = cy.edgehandles( defaults );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>` before js/cytoscape-edgehandles.js script. See demo file in extension: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-edgehandles/blob/master/demo.html